# How to in-place expand an array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

When add an array (A) in an array (B), the PowerShell will treat A itself as an element of B.

Is it possible to in-place expand A, so that all elements of A will be elements of B?

```
$SNs = "0x66", "0x88"

$splat = @(
    'abc',   
    '--serial-number', $SNs,  # How to in-place expand $SNs
    '--sign'
)

Write-Host "Splat Count = " $splat.Count  # will be 4, Expected to be 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `$SNs` in a new line or use semicolon as delimiters instead:

```bash
$SNs = '0x66', '0x88'
$splat = @(
    'abc'
    '--serial-number'; $SNs
    '--sign'
)
$splat.Count

# Or:
$splat = @(
    'abc'
    '--serial-number'
    $SNs
    '--sign'
)
$splat.Count
```

Everything inside the [Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) is enumerated to construct a new array and the commas are preventing that enumeration from happening.

Comment: Tricky but it works. Thanks!